# Dedugging a sort check function in a Linked List

Tags: debugging, kotlin

Background: it is a Linked List (ordering task for delivery), which involves different shopping carts (Node). i need to write a function to check if the carts are sorted according to the totalprice in the Class ShoppingCart.

My questions are:

1. Compiler does not have error message, but my function is false. May I know how or where should i change the code?
2. Any articles about debugging are recommendable for the beginners?

Thanks for the kindness.

Code as below:

1.

```
class OrderProcessing {

    var first: OrderNode? = null

    // Node for linked List
    data class OrderNode(val order: Order, var next: OrderNode?)

....

    fun isSorted(): Boolean {
        var run = first
        var sort = false
        while (run != null) {
            if(run.order.shoppingCart.totalPrice  > run.next!!.order.shoppingCart.totalPrice)
                run = run.next
                sort = true
        }
        return sort
    }
```

2.

```
  Class ShoppingCart () {
        private val shoppingList = mutableListOf<Pair<Product, Int>>
      // totalprice = sum of item price in each cart
       val totalprice : double
    ... }
```

3.

```
  data class Order(
        val shoppingCart: ShoppingCart,
        val address: Address
    )
```

4.

```
  fun main(){

        // while loop until "exit", Menu with functions to add goods to cart, clear cart, show shopping list
```

Answer (score 1):

1. I think in your case you need to start debugging your code and step by step check your program flow.
2. You can read this article - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/debugging-code.html, it's about java but anyway it's a good starting point.